# Call Body of derived method from the base method

Tags: c#

Is there any way to invoke a body of an overriden method from the base?
for example:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public virtual void DoMe()
    {
        using(new UseSomething())
        {
           //invoke the derived method body
        }//end using
    }//end do me 
 }//end base class

public class Der : BaseClass
{
    public override void DoMe()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("der do me");
    }//end do me
}//end der class
```

Comment: If you instanciate the type with the sub class and don't mark the method as virtual, don't really overwrite it and use the new keyword there might be a chance. But I think nobody would recommend it and it would contain some anti patterns.

Comment: Add `DoMe2` as an abstract method in `BaseClass`. Then implement it in `Der` and call it from `DoMe`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you want to call the derived implementation of some logic from inside a context established in the base class (`using(new UseSomething())`).

This strongly implies that the base class has to be inherited from and does not make sense when it's not. This naturally leads to marking it `abstract`, which, in turn, naturally resolves your question:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public void DoMe()
    {
        using (new UseSomething())
        {
            ActualDoMe();
        }
    }

    protected abstract void ActualDoMe();
}

public class Der : BaseClass
{
    protected override void ActualDoMe()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("der do me");
    }
}
```

Comment: That what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe an option is to use the Template Method pattern.

There is a good description here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ocpwK9uesw

So you define your base abstract class as follows;

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public abstract void BeforeMe();

    public abstract void AfterMe();

    public virtual void DoMe()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Executing DoMe of BaseClass");
    }

    public void ExecuteMe()
    {
        BeforeMe();
        DoMe();
        AfterMe();
    }
}
```

Then you have your concrete class as such

```
public class Der: BaseClass
{
    public override void BeforeMe()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Executing BeforeMe of Der class");
    }

    public override void AfterMe()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Executing AfterMe of Der class");
    }
}
```

And then you use it as follows

```
Der myDer = new Der();
myDer.ExecuteMe();
```

Answer (score 0):

No, that won´t work, as `Der.DoMe` may call `BaseClass.DoMe` (by writing `base.DoMe()`). You can´t jump **down** the inheritance-chain, you can only do so in reverse order. Actually your base-class should not make any assumpptions on if or if not the `virtual` method is actually overriden in a derived class. What would you expect if `Der` would not override the method? Anyway this doesn´t mean you can´t call another member within `BaseClass.DoMe` which is `virtual` or even `abstract` and thus results in a call to `Der.AnotherMethod`.

If what you wanted were possible, this would result in an endless recursion, because `base.DoMe` would then call `Der.DoMe` again, which will call `base.DoMe` and so on:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public virtual void DoMe()
    {
        using(new UseSomething())
        {
            //invoke the derived method body
        }
    }
}
public class Der : BaseClass
{
    public override void DoMe()
    {
        base.DoMe(); // this would call the base-method which will then call this method again and so on...
    }
}
```

You should rethink your design. Do not call the derived method from your base- but the base from your derived:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public virtual void DoMe()
    {
        using(new UseSomething())
        {
           // do the real base-stuff
        }
    }
}    
public class Der : BaseClass
{
    public override void DoMe()
    {
        base.DoMe(); // now there´s no endless recursion
        // some additional stuff
    }
}
```

Alternativly create another member which you call from `BaseClass.DoMe`:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public virtual void DoSomething() {  }
    public virtual void DoMe()
    {
        using(new UseSomething())
        {
           DoSomething();  // this will call the most derived member, in our case Der.DoSomething
        }
    }
}    
public class Der : BaseClass
{
    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        // some additional stuff
    }
    public override void DoMe()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Der do me");
    }
}
```

Comment: Calling the derived from the base is a most common pattern. That is why abstract classes even exist.

Comment: @GSerg No, calling **another** member would be common, but not expecting the overridden member to call its overriding one. So `BaseClass.DoMe` may call another `virtual` member which is then overridden. And an abstract method can´t call anything, because it literally has no own implementation at all.

Comment: `calling another member would be common` - and that would be the correct answer, instead of turning it upside down and making the derived explicitly call the base (which would not even work here because the base establishes a context (with `using`) inside which the derived implementation must run).